# CPU usage by kernel modules, routing and forwarding rules

Tags: networking, iptables, kernel-modules

I have a system with a loopback kernel module installed. Through a bunch of routing and iptable rules, packets coming out of the loopback interface are sent over an ipsec tunnel. I am seeing that under load, the kernel panics or dumps a lot of messages that say "BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for X secs".

The stack trace is always in an encryption function like crypto_cbc_encrypt or des3_ede_encrypt. There is a lot of traffic going over the ipsec tunnels and the system is spending lot of time in encryption+decryption.

My concern is that it is always CPU 0. How do I ensure that other CPUs are also sharing the crypto load. I have seen sometimes when the ksoftirq0 thread is at 100%. Again it is always cpu0. This is mostly happening when packets are being forward from the loopback interface, go through the xfrm rules and into the tunnels.

How do I also check the CPU mask for the loopback kernel module? Is there such a thing?

Comment: What processor do you have (exact model), what kernel version, from what distribution? I wonder if you're using a hardware accelerator, what does `/proc/crypto` contain (after using IPsec for a bit: algorithms may be loaded on demand)? I'd be more concerned about the bug than about the CPU balance at this stage. There is no CPU mask for kernel threads AFAIK.

Comment: I am using 10.04 LTS (old, I know, but am stuck with it for now). Processor is a 16 core Xeon E5620. No hardware accelerator. I have also hit the CPU lockup problem in the xfrm gc functions, where in I think the bug I am hitting is fixed by this patch mentioned here - comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network/210854 .